# Stopping a java program from cmd line with two strings input from user?

Tags: java

Hello and thank you in advance for your time. I'm working on a homework assignment that require an input from the user in command line. If the user input the "Exit" or "Quit" My program should quit. I'm able to do one one work but not sure how to do two. ALso the my loop is not looping all time. Can someone shine some light please.

```
import java.io.Console;
public class Echo2{
    public static void main(String [] args){
    String userText = System.console().readLine("Enter some text:"); 
    //System.out.println("*** " + userText + " ***"  );
    if (userText.equals("Exit")){ 
        return;
    }
        else{
        System.out.println("*** " + userText + " ***"  );


        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of the loop you can simply do this:

```
while(true) {
    if (userText.equals("Exit") || userText.equals("Quit")) {
        break;
    }  
}
```

Or if you want to go a little fancy here you can do this

```
 while(true) {
        if ("exit".equals(userText.toLowerString()) || "quit".equals(userText.toLowerString()) {
            break;
        }  
  }
```

the 2nd approach is a little more flexi here, as regardless of the what the user types (this being quit, qUit, EXIT, exIT) the program will convert this to lower case and match within the condition specified

Answer (score 2):

Just use the `||` operator if you want to do more than one check in an `if` statement:

```
if (userText.equals("Exit") || userText.equals("Quit")) { ... }
```

As far as your loop "not looping all the time"; I don't see any loop. Have you failed to include it in your post?

Comment: Thanks for the info on the Exit and Quit. I'm trying to loop the:  String userText = System.console().readLine("Enter some text:");

Comment: The title of your question is about stopping based on two strings which I've helped you with. You don't have a loop in your program so there's no way to help with that part. @ericrk00

Comment: @MaciejCygan, I don't trouble myself pondering such things :)

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils still one should not downvote if the answer is correct - trolls :(

Comment: As you can tell, I'm new to Java and also to Stack. Thanks for the input.